# How to develop an android studio plugin that adds a dependency to the build.gradle?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, build.gradle, intellij-plugin

I am trying to build an **Android Studio plugin with a UI** to **add** a **dependency to the build.gradle file**. How can we add a line of dependency programmatically into the build.gradle file from my Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps. Make sure you have added gradle dependancy (`<depends>org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle</depends>`) to you plugin project's `plugin.xml`.

1. Create a `VirtualFile` representing the `build.gradle` file you wan't to modify.

   ```
   VirtualFile buildFile = LocalFileSystem.getInstance().findFileByPath("absolute path to build.gradle");
   ```
2. Create `GradleBuildModel` for that file.

   ```
   GradleBuildModel gradleBuildModel = GradleBuildModel.parseBuildFile(buildFile, project);
   ```
3. Get `DependenciesModel` from `GradleBuildModel`

   ```
   DependenciesModel dependenciesModel = buildModel.dependencies();
   ```
4. Add your dependency.

   ```
   dependenciesModel.addArtifact(COMPILE, "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2");
   //import static com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.dependencies.CommonConfigurationNames.COMPILE;
   ```
5. Finally, apply changes.

   ```
   ApplicationManager.getApplication().runWriteAction(() -> {
       CommandProcessor.getInstance().executeCommand(project, () -> {
           gradleBuildModel.applyChanges();
       }, null, null);
   });
   ```